# Android Edit Text and Save To Http Server

Tags: android, json, rest, http

```
package com.nusecond.suredeal.app.suredeal.activity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.R;
import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.suredeal.pojo.ConsumerProfile;

import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyPreferences extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<ConsumerProfile>cp = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_preferences);
        Log.d("Consumer pojo", "onCreate:");
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();



    }
    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ConsumerProfile>{



        @Override
        protected ConsumerProfile doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = "http://192.168.1.213:9001/consumer/local/"+LoginFragment.CONSUMEROBJECT.getId();
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                ConsumerProfile cp = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ConsumerProfile.class);
                return cp;
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(),e );

            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ConsumerProfile cp){
            super.onPostExecute(cp);
            Log.d("cppppppppppppppppppppp", "onPostExecute: " + cp.getId());

            TextView fname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editfname);
            TextView mname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editmname);
            TextView lname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editlname);
            TextView nname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editnname);
            TextView dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editdob);
            TextView status=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editstatus);
            TextView homeAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edithomeAddr);
            TextView workAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editworkAddr);
            TextView income=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editincome);
            fname.setText(cp.getFirstName());
            mname.setText(cp.getMiddleName());
            lname.setText(cp.getLastName());
            nname.setText(cp.getNickName());
            dob.setText(cp.getDob());
            status.setText(cp.getStatus());
            homeAddress.setText(cp.getHomeAddress());
            workAddress.setText(cp.getWorkAddress());
            income.setText(cp.getIncome());

        }

    }

}
```

1. This is Activity To Display JSON Data In My Android App.
2. My Main Aim is to allow The user to Edit And Update The Details.
3. Up to now I'm able to Display the Data from Http Service to My App.
4. Next step is to allow the User to edit the details and Save back to service.
5. I'm new to android any Help Thankful to them.

---

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="firstName"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editfname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="middleName"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editmname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lastName"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editlname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="nickName"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editnname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dob"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editdob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="status"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editstatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="homeAddress"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edithomeAddr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="workAddress"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editworkAddr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="income"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editincome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Update Preferences"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

1. This my Layout file.
2. After editing the preferences.
3. If update button is selected it should update back to server.
4. And also how to add Vertical Scroll View.
5. Any Help Very much Thankful.

---

[This is the screen I'm getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP1fC.png)

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Retrofit instead of RestTemplate. Saves a lot of time. And so to your question - make an POST or PUT endpoint on server side and then prepare request to send this data to the server. http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: The end point of put method is same as get method url@Nekromancer

Answer (score 0):

1) On Update button click start httppost request which is responsible for sending data to server..

you can parse all value in jsonobject

```
    String url= "YOUR URL";

    JSONObject data=new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("firstname", "abc");
        data.put("lastname", "xyz");
        data.put("dob", "11-03-2016");
        data.put("status", "ac");
        data.put("homeaddress", "cac");

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data.toString());
            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"); 
            httppostreq.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(httppostreq);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); /*.. read entity here..*/
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
```

2)
For Scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- your layout element -->
.....
.....
.....

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```